# Who was the original iOS designer?

Tags: ios, design

I read somewhere that the new iOS7 design is an old project of the current designer, and that it was adopted now because the original iOS designer left the company.

**Update:**

This is the post I'm referring to.

[What 5 Dots In iOS 7 Reveal About A Decade Of Apple Design Strife](http://www.fastcodesign.com/1672802/what-5-dots-in-ios7-reveal-about-a-decade-of-apple-design-strife)

Comment: Is there a practical question you are trying to solve? Without a link or more details on what "designer" means this seems more about discussion or trivia/history than a problem to solve.

Comment: @bmike By designer, I mean [someone who designs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Designer)

Comment: Are we in to the Apple internal politics now?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but those comments are a little on the defensive, what is wrong with asking who was the responsible for the design of the old iOS system. I'm just curious.

Comment: Seriously dude, SE isn't a google alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Scott Forstall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Forstall) is an American software engineer who was the senior vice president (SVP) of iOS Software at Apple Inc. from 2007 until October 2012.
>
> [Sir Jonathan Paul "Jony" Ive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Ive), KBE RDI (born 27 February 1967)[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Forstall) is an English designer and the Senior Vice President of Design at Apple Inc. He has the overall responsibility for Industrial Design and also provides leadership and direction for Human Interface (HI) software teams across the company.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Ive) He is the lead designer of many of Apple's products, including the MacBook Pro, iMac, MacBook Air, iPod, iPod Touch, iPhone, iPad, iPad Mini and iOS 7.

Comment: So, Scott Forstall  was the original iOS designer, or both Scott Forstall and Jony Ive?

Comment: There wasn't "one designer." Scott Forstall's teams competed internal against Fadell's and ultimately it would be Forstall's team that Jobs' would favor. But he did not "design" iOS. He managed the teams that did (which includes freelance designers that don't even work in Cupertino). There is a vast distinction between the statements.

Comment: This is a nice attempt to answer objectively, but the question is too vague and broad to be answered in the stack exchange framework. Lets see if the question can be made into something practical rather than a hypothetical discussion of what it means to be the "sole designer" of a product.

Comment: Not worth my time to do anything more than a google query for this type of question. Seriously, LMGTFY links should be allowed on this site; this is a waste of our time.